# hot to join listItem(checkboxItem) and DataSet Row using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have problem I try to join listItem(checkboxItem) and DataSet Row using linq to make listItem(checkboxItem) in Selected

```
private void BindCheckboxList()
{
    int resID = Convert.ToInt32(hf_resID.Value);
    DataSet skillDS = Skill.GetSkillsForResousrce(resID);


    //checked pre selected items 
    var query = from ListItem li in chblSkills.Items
                join dsRow in skillDS.Tables[0].Rows
                on li.Value equals ds
                select ListItem;

    foreach (ListItem li in query)
        ListItem.selected = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
    var query = from ListItem li in chblSkills.Items
            from dsRow in skillDS.Tables[0].Rows
            where li.Value == dsRow["ColumnName"]
            select ListItem
```

Your 'where' need to be an expression eligible to an 'if' statement.